# Nested If Statements to lead to a Sum in a Matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

I'm trying to write if 3 conditions are satisfied in a row, add a number in that row to a list of all the other numbers whose row's also satisfy those 3 cases.

Right now I have:

```
=SUM(IF(RawData!$A$2:$A$2000, "< "&A16, IF(RawData!$B$2:$B$2000, "*Name*", 
IF(RawData!$C$2:$C$2000, "*String*", RawData!$F$2:$F$2000))))
```

If A certain date is less than another date in a row (A2:A2000) is less than a row in a cell (A16), and a row(B2:B2000) contains the string "Name", and a row(C2:C2000) contains the string "String", then sum together the number in that row in column F(F2:F2000).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is what you have not working? I have a feeling that you need to remove the space in `"< "&` so it's just `"<"&A16`.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  The only thing I notice is I don't have my "else" case anywhere of a "0."  Do I maybe have to put that inside each if for the false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF does not use string literals and does not use wild cards,

You can use a simple SUMIFS for this, which does both:

```
=SUMIFS(RawData!$F$2:$F$2000,RawData!$A$2:$A$2000,"<" & A16, RawData!$B$2:$B$2000, "*Name*",RawData!$C$2:$C$2000, "*String*")
```

Comment: Is this a typo: "RawData!$F$2:$F$2000RawData!"?  That currently is giving me an #ERROR response.

Comment: If I want to also add up everything that does not fit this case, is there any easy way to say not contain "String?"

Comment: I tried "<>*String*" but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: It works for me.  Not sure why it does not work for you.  You do have two other criteria that may be effecting it. @obizues